# Grok Help While Loops Not ending Loop

Tags: python-3.x

I was doing the grok NCSS challenge and when I was doing a problem about where you have to ask the user for an input for a tv channel, then when 3 channels have the substring 'dig' in it it sorts the channels with dig and prints them. My results gave an infinite loop and never progresses. Expected result:

```
Channel name: Dignify
Channel name: Tardigrades
Channel name: Underdog
Channel name: paradigm
Proposals: paradigm, Tardigrades, Dignify
```

My result:

```
Channel name: Dignify
Channel name: Tardigrades
Channel name: Underdog
Channel name: paradigm
Channel name:
```

Infinitly
Here is my code:

```
words = []
channel = input('Channel name: ')
channel.lower()
count = 0
while count <= 3:
  if 'dig' in channel:
    count += 1
    words.append(channel)
  channel = input('Channel name: ')
  channel.lower()
words.sort()
print(f'Proposals: {words[0]}, {words[1]}, {words[2]}')
```

Comment: Your result looks correct?!

Comment: Would you amend the title to contain a specific question? (The name of the challenge isn't all that useful - see if you can make it a question about Python instead).

Comment: Well It is not working for some reason

Comment: wait my result actually went infinitely asking channel name but I will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve the problem

```
words = []

while len(words) < 3:
    channel = input("Channel name: ")
    if "dig" in channel.lower():
        words.append(channel)

print(f'Proposals: {", ".join(words[::-1])}')
```

Result:

```
Channel name: Dignify
Channel name: Tardigrades
Channel name: Underdog
Channel name: paradigm
Proposals: paridigm, Tardigrades, Dignify
```